# use devtools imported packages in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, devtools

I am developing a page with devtools and using DESCRIPTION imports to load appropriate packages. I also added a Shiny app to my package structure ([according to the article](https://deanattali.com/2015/04/21/r-package-shiny-app/)), so it looks as the following:

```html
- mypacakge
  |- inst
     |- shiny-examples
        |- myapp
           |- ui.R
           |- server.R
  |- R
     |- runExample.R
     |- ...
  |- DESCRIPTION
  |- ...
```

Now, the shiny app works when I add the `library` instructions at the top of the ui/server files. Is there any way to not paste these instructions, but simply use the DESCRIPTION imported packages? And also, is there any way to make shiny app see package functions from in R folder without running `devtools::load_all` in Shiny?

Comment: Does it cause a problem to add the `library` instruction ? What would you like to get rid of it ?

Comment: As I read in the [Hadley's package creation guide](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz), it is better to declare libraries by import in packages, rather than to have library/require in function definitions. For clarity, I would like to stick to that principle, as it is the Shiny app that I am attaching to the package.